# Trying to extract an xml file stored as a blob from a database and storing the extracted xml data in a php object

Tags: php, xml

I currently have a database which contains xml files stored as blobs. When I attempt to extract this data using sql I am not getting the data in the original xml format rather just bits of text from the xml file. I have tried a number of ways but no luck so far anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

The aim is to determine which xml file is needed for comparison, to retrieve it from the database and compare it to another xml file.

Heres one thing I've been trying:

```
                **//************THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS*************************
                if($databaseMatchedModelsObjects[$count] -> version == $maxVersion && $databaseMatchedModelsObjects[$count] -> release == $maxRelease){
                    $con2 = connect2();
                    $contentModel = $con2->prepare("SELECT fileName, type, size, content FROM model WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1");
                        //print_r($databaseMatchedModelsObjects[$count] -> mid);
                        $contentModel->bindParam('id',$databaseMatchedModelsObjects[$count] -> mid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $contentModel->execute(array('id'=>$databaseMatchedModelsObjects[$count] -> mid));
                        $row = $contentModel->fetch();
                        //$sql_statement= "SELECT xmltype(content, nls_charset_id('CHAR_CS')).getclobval() rfile FROM model WHERE id =" . $databaseMatchedModelsObjects[$count] -> id;
                        //$sql_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_prim);
                        //print_r($sql_result);
                        //if($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        if($row) {
                        $finalModelToCompareTo = $row['content'];
                        //echo(simplexml_load_string());
                        //print_r(simplexml_load_string($finalModelToCompareTo));
                        //print_r($finalModelToCompareTo);
                        //$finalModelToCompareTo = $databaseMatchedModelsObjects[$count] -> content;
                        //print_r($databaseMatchedModelsObjects[$count] -> content);

                    }

               }
```

Example print out using var dump of the content, just a snippet full print out is too long. This should be in xml format.

```
string(15513) " G title sub title 0 English 0 date This is the top level of the Common Information Model.   This model contains the singleton, root Managed Object Class (MOC) ManagedElement under which the complete model is contained. Directly under ManagedElement are managed-function level classes SF, T, E and the root MOC of any managed functions. The Equipment Root MOC is in the Equipment Managed Object Model (MOM). The root MOC for a managed function is hosted in the managed function MOM. Deprecated, Contains product information for a Managed Element and ManagedFunction(s).  Replaced by ProductData The product number in ABC format.  For information, refer to Corporate Basic Standards. The product revision in the form R[1-9][A-Z].  For information, refer to Corporate Basic Standards. Common product name.
```

XML File that I will be comparing against Sample code:

How it is printed in comparison:

```
$uploaded_model = @simplexml_load_file($targetdir . "\\" . $fileinfo->getFilename()); print_r($uploaded_model);

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [dtdVersion] => G [momMetaData] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [momTitle] => title [momSubTitle] => sub title [momIdentity] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [docNum] => 0 [docLang] => English [docRev] => 0 [docDate] => date ) [createdBy] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [signature] => xqichen ) ) [mim] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [author] => XQHE [contact] => ok@dektech.com.au [correction] => 0 [date] => 2014-11-22 [docNo] => [name] => CmwPm [namespace] => urn:com:CmwPm [namespacePrefix] => cmwpm [organization] => XDT/DEK [release] => 2 [revision] => A [version] => 2 ) [description] => Performance Management MOM. 3GPP defines Performance Management in 3GPP 32.401. [domainExtension] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [domain] => ECIM ) [extension] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => MomName [value] => PM ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Version [value] => 2 ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => ecimMomRelease [value] => 3 ) ) [3]
=> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => ecimMomCorrection [value] => 0 ) ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => immNamespace [value] => MOM_NAME ) ) ) ) [implements] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [correction] => 0 [name] => ECIM_PM [release] => 3 [version] => 2 ) ) [struct] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes]
=> Array ( [name] => MeasurementReaderNameValue ) [description] => This name value is used for real-time monitoring. The real-time monitoring is set up using a PM job of type REALTIMEJOB. [structMember] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => currentValue ) [description] => Contains the real-time value of the measurement. This value can be read in conjunction with attribute lastUpdated to determine the value of counters in real time. [string] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => lastUpdated ) [description] => Contains the exact time the currentValue was last set. This attribute is used to determine how recent the value supplied in currentValue is. [derivedDataTypeRef] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => DateTime ) [mimName] => CmwPm ) )
```

Comment: posted the code above

Comment: waaay too much code. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (M stands for Minimal).

Comment: sorry about that updated with problem code

Comment: Much better :) Please also show us what those "bits of text from the xml file" look like, e.g. an excerpt of `var_dump($row['content'])` highlighting the suspicious bits compared to the text you originally inserted.

Comment: Updated with result of var_dump($row['content'])

Comment: Unfortunately, one cannot see the problem in your last edit. Perhaps a screenshot would help better. Or else just explain in plain english what characters/sequences/whatnot are altered. Or do you mean that all XML tags are absent from the string you get back from the database?

Comment: BTW, if you read the string in your browser, remember that the browser will try to interpret the string as HTML, effectvely hiding (virtually) all XML tags. Look at the HTML source directly (CTRL + U in most browsers).

Comment: Ok I checked the html browser and yes the tags do appear in the html source directly. However I need the xml file retrieved from the database to be represented as a SimpleXMLObject like the above so that I can compare the two including the tags. I've included the code for that and how I printed it, its retrieved from a file directly rather than the database.

Comment: I still cannot see a problem here. What do you get from the database, and what did you expect?

Comment: What I get from the database is the printout as a result from var_dump. I need that to be in the format of a SimpleXMLObject the same way the other xml file is but it seems to be a different format. There are two xml files I need to compare, both need to be SimpleXMLObject format, one is in the correct format, however the one that is extracted from the database isn't.

Comment: Problem solved as shown in my answer, thank you RandomSeed for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my problem by:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($finalModelToCompareTo);
```

The XML seems to have been converted to string within the blob and you need to use this method to convert it back to a `SimpleXMLObject` again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really IS a XML file. The `string(15513) " G title sub title 0 En...` representation is the same XML file parsed by the browser and you only see the plaintext values but not the XML tags. So, don't worry about the losses you see in the printout. If you open up the webpage source using **Ctrl+U** you can see the complete XML file syntax.